# Confused about useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm building my first Custom React Hook and am confused about what I think is a simple aspect of the code:

```
export const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { app } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log('** Inside useFetch: options = ', options);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('**** Inside useEffect: options = ', options);
    const fetchData = async function() {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await axios.get(url, options);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setData(response.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return { loading, data };
};
```

I pass to `useFetch` two parameters: A url and a `headers` object that contains an AWS Cognito authorization key that looks like this: `Authorization: eyJraWQiOiJVNW...` (shortened for brevity)

When I do this the `options` object on does exist near within `useFetch` but within the `useEffect` construct it is empty.  YET the `url` string is correctly populated in BOTH cases.

This makes no sense to me.  Might anyone have an idea why this is occurring?

Comment: I believe it's an async timing issue.  I added `options` as dependency in `useEffect` and now it appears to work.  That said, there are now 2 calls to the API Endpoint with the first one returning a `401` error.  I guess I can put an `if ... then` construct around async function call though that inherently seems wrong.

Comment: The bottom of my code now looks like this:
```
    if (options) {
      fetchData();
    };
  }, [options]);
```
However, the function is being called twice from the parent component.  I don't yet know if this is because of a flaw in the code I've been discussing or something in the parent component.

Comment: As explained in my answer below I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the component using this hook, not the hook itself. Could you provide more code showing how you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Below an implementation of your code showing that it works as expected.

The async/await has been converted to a Promise but should have the same behavior.

**"Inside use fetch"** is outputed 3 times:

1. on mount (`useEffect(()=>..., []`)
2. after first state change (`setLoading(true)`)
3. after second state change (`setLoading(false)`)

and **"Inside use effect"** is outputed 1 time on mount (`useEffect(()=>..., []`)

Since it doesn't work for you this way it could mean that when the component mounts, options is not available yet.

You confirm it when saying that when you put options as a dependency, useEffect is called two times with the first fetch failing (most likely because of options missing).

I'm pretty sure you will find the problem with options in the parents of the component using your custom hook.

```js
const axios = {
    get: (url, options) => {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ status: 200, data: 'Hello World' }), 2000));
    }
  };
  
  const AppContext = React.createContext({ app: null });
  
  const useFetch = (url, options) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const { app } = React.useContext(AppContext);
    console.log('** Inside useFetch: options = ', JSON.stringify(options));
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('**** Inside useEffect: options = ', JSON.stringify(options));
      const fetchData = function () {
          setLoading(true);
          const response = axios.get(url, options)
            .then(response => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                setData(response.data);
              }
              setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              setLoading(false);
              throw error;
            });

      };
      fetchData();
    }, []);
  
    return { loading, data };
  };
  
  const App = ({url, options}) => {
    const { loading, data } = useFetch(url, options);
    return (
      <div
          style={{
              display: 'flex', background: 'red',
              fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: 'bold',
              justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',
              width: 300, height: 60, margin: 5
          }}
      >
        {loading ? 'Loading...' : data}
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App
        url="https://www.dummy-url.com"
        options={{ headers: { Authorization: 'eyJraWQiOiJVNW...' } }}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  So `options` is populated with an AWS Access Token header string, which is permanently stored for each session here: `const { appStore } = useContext(AppContext);` Above the `useEffect` construct I do this:
```
    var options;
    if (appStore.awsConfig) {
      options = appStore.awsConfig;
    }
```
It's still confusing to me why the `appStore.awsConfig` value isn't instantly available ... but it isn't!  It *appears* that the Context API data store has an async nature to it, which I didn't expect.

Comment: I don't think context is async. It may be because the session is populated when a higher ancestor mounts. A component mounts when all his children have mounted, so by the time the component using your hook mounts, his ancestors have not mounted yet....